# What protocol is used for the built-in microSD slot on the RPi3?

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, spi

[image]

The datasheet above shows different pin configurations for SD and SPI modes on either SD or microSD cards. 
Does the built-in microSD slot on the Raspberry Pi 3 B use SPI or SD mode for activities like booting, writing, reading and more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know.

The early model Pi [schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Rev-2.1-Model-AB-Schematics.pdf) show SD connections to GPIO 48-53 marked as SD.CLK, SD.CMD, SD.DAT1-SD.DAT4 which suggests SD.

However the same GPIO may well be used in a SPI mode during boot.